# Split String with double regex java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have String like this :

```
String s = "PLAN\\ORG\\b.PDF";
```

How can I split them  like this:

PLAN

ORG

b.PDF

I tried the code below:

```
String[] data = s.split("\\");
```

But it show error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the special characters, that you need to escape by using slash:

```
String[] data = s.split("\\\\");
```

[In the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) you can find additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use StringTokenizer in this case. It would be faster than using Split. Would matter if you are doing it many times.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("PLAN\\ORG\\b.PDF","\\");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: in my case, using split string is more appropriate because i need to add split strings into an array